# Why does the jQuery stop working second time the action was made?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a page where once you switch the select's tag option it will give you a different result, but when I switched to "Question #1" option, chosed one of the other choices and again chosed "Question #1" option it wouldn't run.

```
function testselect() {

    var x = document.getElementById("testselect").value;

    if (x == "") {

        $(function() {

            $("#demo").html("");

        });

    }

    else {

        $(function() {

            $("#demo").load("c7vt.php?finished");


        });

    }

}
```

And HTML:

```
<select id="question" onchange="question()">

    <option>Select Question #</option>
    <option value="1">Question #1</option>
    <option value="2">Question #2</option>
    <option value="3">Question #3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Can you share your html? What you are asking exactly isn't clear, could you edit your question? It might be better if you change the part that says "a different result" to a specific result. You could get rid of the `$("#demo").load()` call and change it for something like `$("#demo").html()`, it would be easier for others to test your code. Have a look at [mcve]. Also, don't need to wrap the jquery calls inside functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML onclick is calling a "question()" function but your JavaScript has a "testselect()" function. Also the JavaScript is getting the value from "#testselect" but the ID is actually "#question". Both of the jQuery doc ready functions need removed as well. Last thing to mention is that "x" will never be empty because the option with no value will render the option text which would be "Select Question #". Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="question">
    <option value="default">Select Question #</option>
    <option value="1">Question #1</option>
    <option value="2">Question #2</option>
    <option value="3">Question #3</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#question").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var x = document.getElementById("question").value;

        if (x == "default") {
            $("#demo").html("");
        } else {
            $("#demo").load("c7vt.php?finished");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured that’s what happened given you did have it working somewhat but wanted to make sure. Glad I could offer a solution that worked for you! Could you mark it answered when you have a chance?